# How do I receive progress information for git push?

Tags: git

I'm attempting to migrate a pre-existing project from TFVC to git. I'm able to successfully perform the conversion locally. However, when I attempt to push to the new git remote, the process seems to hang indefinitely. (There is a large amount of data -- a few hundred MiB)

Using the command `git push --verbose --progress`, I receive the following output (with irrelevant text removed):

```
Pushing to {...}
Counting objects: {...}, done
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% {...}, done.
Writing objects: 100% {...}, done
Total {...}
POST git-receive-pack ({...} bytes)
```

The first 6 lines appear quickly, and progress is shown on the "Compressing objects" line. When it gets to the "POST git-receive-pack" line, no progress is shown, causing the process to appear as if it was hanging. I would expect to be able to see a percentage complete of the number of bytes uploaded. Is this possible?

I'm using git version "2.6.2.windows.1".

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you can push successfully, but you wish you could see a percentage complete?

If so, it may be a limitation of the windows port, it seems to automatically work on linux: `Writing objects:  66% (2/3), 44.75 MiB | 4.54 MiB/s`

Comment: If I batch up the commits, and push those in sequence, instead of the entire branch at once, then I'm able to push successfully. It's possible that the lack of progress is a Windows limitation. The odd thing is that the "Writing objects" step happens immediately, but displays a speed of "0 bytes/s". The part that's slow is the "POST git-receive-pack" step